# Show data using PyQt and ROS interfaces

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, pyqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how can I see my data on PyQt that I published with ROS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402175/show-data--using-pyqt-and-ros-interfaces/) by [gurselturkeri](https://answers.ros.org/users/99062/gurselturkeri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2022-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use any of the messages in the `rqt_common_plugins` package to show the PyQT data that is published with ROS. To do this, make sure you have installed the `rqt` package.

rqt: http://wiki.ros.org/rqt 
rqt_common_plugins: http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_common_plugins?distro=noetic

---

Originally posted by [qilin_gundamenjoyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/105678/qilin_gundamenjoyer/) with karma: 81 on 2022-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0